# MongoDB aggregration ignores index order

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

In order to select the 100 newest documents from `MongoDB`, where each document is composed from multiple documents in the same collection that have a similar field (in this case `timestamp`), I'm using the following series of queries in `Node.js`:

```
        return q.ninvoke(collection, 'aggregate',
            [
                {
                    $match  : { active: true }
                },
                {
                    $limit  : 100
                },
                {
                    $group  : {
                        _id         : "$timestamp",
                        mintime : {
                            $min        : "$seconds"
                        },
                        timestamp   : {
                            $first      : "$timestamp"
                        },
                        data        : {
                            $first      : "$data"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]);
```

This works fine when there are less than `$limit` documents in the collection. When there are more, it selects the oldest documents (inserted first), not the documents with the highest `timestamp` (which is often but not always the last one inserted).

This is unexpected, as documents are inserted into the collection with the following ensured index:

```
collection.ensureIndex({
    timestamp   : -1,
    seconds     : -1,
    active      : -1
}, {
    sparse : false
});
```

I was under the impression that the `-1` first index on `timestamp` meant that they were indexed in descending order, resulting in a collection where the first `$limit` documents would always be the ones with the highest `timestamp`.

Why doesn't this work as expected?
Am I wrong?

Comment: you need to sort before you limit to get the desired result

Comment: @Sebastian Why? That would mean sorting through thousands of documents. Index order is specifically designed to prevent such overhead, isn't it?

Comment: no, it is there to make sorting more efficient. It does not mean all your queries are automatically sorted. To make use of the index you need to sort.

Comment: If a limited selection is not automatically confined to the indexed order, then why do we need to specify that order in the index?

Comment: @Sebastian the problem is clearly with the **`$match`** selection not finding an index if you look closely. Sorting has nothing to do with this. I see the temptation, but in all likelihood "timestamp" actually reflects the insertion order. So if anything, that should be the secondary key of a compound index.

Comment: @NeilLunn Maybe I don't understand the question here but if I need the *latest* 100 documents I need to sort by some timestamp.

Comment: @Sebastian Read the additional information I put in the answer I provided. It is all about *selecting* the index in the first place. Remember that **`aggregate()`** has no option to **`hint()`**. You need to be very specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually your real problem here is that index is not being selected. You can check this via the `explain` option ( available in MongoDB 2.6 or actually from MongoDB 2.4.9 though not documented ) from the `db.runCommand` form of invoking aggregate.

With MongoDB it is **very** important to specify the field you wish to use in a index when matching **first**. So an index defined as:

```
collection.ensureIndex({ "active": 1 })
```

Or even with `-1` would get selected in this case. Your index does not because you did not reference any of the other fields.

This *can* force over larger selections, when the optimizer recognizes this would be the *optimal* case, but this actually appears to be [broken](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-13197) in current 2.6 releases (until fixed).

**Addendum**: So there is possibly a "sorting" component to be involved, but that is more about how you specify the compound index yet again. To ensure you "timestamp" values are in order for the grouping boundaries, make sure you include that after the initial selector, as in:

```
collection.ensureIndex({ "active": -1, "timestamp": -1 })
```

In your required order.

Comment: Thanks for your response Neil Lunn. Unfortunately, I don't seem to understand what you mean exactly, as I _am_ indexing the fields I am querying. Also, the most important index is `timestamp`, as `active` is only a boolean to ignore certain records and there is no problem with this mechanism. It's all in which documents get selected, `timestamp`-wise. Hence, I am probably misunderstanding you. Can you elaborate and suggest how to improve my query?

Comment: @Redsandro Hopefully one more edit I added clears this up. But most important is the **order** in which you specify the fields in the index needs to match the order in which you *query* them. Otherwise the index is not selected. Very important for the **`$match`** phase of aggregation. Or any query in fact.

Comment: If I understand correctly, what I _thought_ about `index` __order__ was the following: _"Otherwise the index may not be efficient"_ - is in fact - _"Otherwise the index is __ignored completely__."_ Are you certain? This would mean it's impossible to do a separate query where it matches on something else than `active`, while still enjoying the soothing speed of the index.

Comment: @Redsandro Absolutely. Have a look at the index you specified in your question and how that differs from the definitions I have given. The query optimizer in MongoDB expects the fields to be accessed in the **order** they are referenced in order for it to select that index for usage. Your **`$match`** is on `active` as a field. So that field **needs** to be the first element of any index selected. Except of course in the case that I mentioned, which I also mentioned in currently broken due to a major refactor of the indexing API. Who reported that issue again? :)

Comment: I see now. Having a 3-field compound index does not mean I can query any of the indexed fields. It means I must __select the fields in the order or the index exactly.__ Your answer does indeed say this, but when [my] understanding of the index rules is incorrect, your answer can be read as: _"It is important to use (any kind of) select (aka $match) statement __first__ (before using any other statements)",_ which I did. Thank you for your patient reply. I would phrase it a bit different, but I'm happy to accept!

Comment: Also, now that I have a correct understanding of indexes, I figured that the easiest solution to keep a re-usable index that makes sense speedwise (and having a boolean as primary index does not make sense), is to insert a faux-match to adhere to the index order: 

`$match : { timestamp : { $gt : 0 }, seconds : { $gte : 0 }, active: true }`.

This way, the index doesn't have to reorder everything every time an active boolean is changed.

Comment: Lesson 3 could be: Don't forget that you can have multiple compound indexes.

Answer (score 0):

Very important answer to supplement the one given by @NeilLunn:

I don't know the technical details, but even the correct statement can consistently select wrong documents from the index **if your diskspace is "low".** Mongo might not even complain about this, it will just select wrong documents.

Even though MongoDB will create four sparse files of a gigabyte each, Mongo can still choke if the free space drops **below a gigabyte.**

If this happens, free up **at least two gigabytes** and defragment the data:

- ## /etc/init.d/mongodb stop
- ## mongod --repair
- ## /etc/init.d/mongodb start

As a rule of thumb I would say: Keep at least 2̶G̶B̶ 2 + 4 = 6GB free at all times.